# How To Solve This Database Update Error In Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, sql-update

I'm creating a web site. And I have created a registration page. I want to update my details. When I click Edit button in AdminPanel.blade.php it gives me all the details in AdminUpdate.blade.php. After I change the data and when I click the Update User button , it gives me this error. - " Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. "

How can I Fix this ??

Here is my AdminPanel.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

<tr>
<td> Name </td>
</tr>


@foreach($data as $value )
<tr>
<td> {{ $value->username }} </td>
<td> <a href="edit/{{ $value->id }}"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="btn-primary"></a> </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Here is my AdminPanelController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
$edd = User::find($id);
//dd($edd);
      return view('AdminUpdate', ['edd' => $edd]);

}

    public function adminedit($id, Request $request)
{
    // Add Validation

    $users = User::find($id);
$users->username = $request->get('username');
$users->email = $request->get('email');
$users->save();

return redirect('AdminPanel');
}
```

Here is my AdminUpdate.blade.php

```
<form action="adminedit/{{ $edd->id }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{$edd->username}}" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email : *</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$edd->email}}" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{$edd->password}}" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Profile Picture :</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file_img" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">If U Want , U Can Skip Upload A Profile Picture</small>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update User">
                    </form>
```

Here are my Routes.

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@edit');

Route::put('/adminedit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@adminedit');
```

Update To @Alex

```
<form action="/adminedit/2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="eECno3BdT86XYW2PfLjxL4ABtekEBLbxFvDmxY9y">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="head_slsoc_1" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email : *</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="kistlakr@gmail.com" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="asd" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Profile Picture :</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file_img" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">If U Want , U Can Skip Upload A Profile Picture</small>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update User">
                    </form>
```

Comment: Your route method(POST) are not same with your view blade file(PUT)!

Comment: @HirenGohel - It still gives me the same error. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: Try to also change: `<form action="/adminedit/{{ $edd->id }}" method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data">
`

Comment: @HirenGohel - Now it gives me 404 not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `PUT` method:

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Change the route to:

```
Route::put('/adminedit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@adminedit');
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: @Kistlak change it to `action="/adminedit/{{ $edd->id }}"` and show me generated HTML if it'll not work.

Comment: Now it gives me 404 not found.

Comment: I added to post.

Comment: @Kistlak you've shown Blade template and not HTML generated by Blade.

Comment: @Kistlak now you've shown PHP generated by Blade engine. Just got to the browser and click something like `View page code`.

Comment: You mean view page source ?? Now ?? :o

Comment: @Kistlak yes, but not HTML of the error page. Please show HTML of the form.

Comment: @Kistlak HTML looks fine but maybe you're using wrong web server configuration. Try to use the `url()` helper `<form action="{{ url('adminedit/' . $edd->id') }}" ....`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '')); ?>" method="post" enctype' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' (View: D:\wamp64\www\FinalProject\resources\views\AdminUpdate.blade.php)

Comment: <form action="{{ url('adminedit/' . $edd->id') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @Kistlak remove redundant `'` symbol `"{{ url('adminedit/' . $edd->id) }}"`

Comment: Its Working !! :D Thank U Very Much Bro !! 
But, whats the error ?? Still I have no idea..

Answer (score 2):

for this change `method="post"` to  method="PUT"

and write your route like

```
Route::put('/adminedit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@adminedit');
```